# JavaScript take part of an array

Tags: javascript

How can I create a new array that contains all elements numbered nth to (n+k)th from an old array?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You want the [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method.

```
var newArray = oldArray.slice(n, n+k);
```

Comment: While W3Schools doesn't appear to have any errors on that page (which is unusual), I think the MDC documentation is better: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answer (score 17):

i think the slice method will do what you want.

```
arrayObject.slice(start,end)
```

Answer (score 5):

Slice creates shallow copy, so it doesn't create an exact copy. For example, consider the following:

```
var foo = [[1], [2], [3]];
var bar = foo.slice(1, 3);
console.log(bar); // = [[2], [3]]
bar[0][0] = 4;
console.log(foo); // [[1], [4], [3]]
console.log(bar); // [[4], [3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Prototype Solution:

```
Array.prototype.take = function (count) {
    return this.slice(0, count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> lets say we have an array of six objects, and we want to get first three
>   objects.

**Solution :**

```
var arr = [{num:1}, {num:2}, {num:3}, {num:4}, {num:5}, {num:6}];
arr.slice(0, 3); //will return first three elements
```