# How to do [:] like in Python but in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

in Python, you can get a list like this (array in JavaScript)

```py
a = ["one", "two", "three"]
print(a[:]) # ["one", "two", "three"]
```

I'm wondering how I can do this too but in JavaScript. If it is possible, please tell me :)

Comment: if `a[:]` does a shallow copy of a, then the equivalent would be `[...a]`

Comment: what if I wanted to do a[:1] to get only ["one", "two"]? @RameshReddy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript take part of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716403/javascript-take-part-of-an-array)

Comment: Don't ask "how can I do the equivalent of <language X code> in language Y?", unless that is the only way you can describe the problem. It is much better to ask directly how to do *the thing that you want the code to do* - in this case, either *copy* (if you specifically mean `[:]`) or *slice* (the general concept) the Javascript array. And having figured this out, you are well on your way to using a search engine to find an answer.

Comment: Please also only tag languages that are relevant to *the problem itself*, not to how you have decided to describe the problem. Just as you wouldn't tag your IDE unless you were asking a question about how to use the IDE. A question should only have multiple language tags if you *must* write code in *each tagged language* in order to solve the problem *and* that code must interoperate (if the pieces of code stand on their own, then you have separate questions about each).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, `a[:]` creates a shallow copy of the array. The equivalent in JS is `[...a]`.

If you just want to get the first two elements, you can use `a.slice(0, 2)` which returns a new array. The slice method goes from the starting index (inclusive) to the ending index (non-inclusive).

Comment: Thanks! The solution is by using the slice method. I played around with it until I eventually understand how it works.